# JQ get all simple values in json

Tags: json, jq, scalar

I have a json structure which contains nested dictionaries and I want to fetch all the simple values in it (String, Int, bool etc but not dict and lists).

How can I achieve this using JQ.

Example:

```
{
    "a": 10,
    "b": {
        "d": 20,
        "e": "hello"
    },
    "c": {
        "z": {
            "f": true
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output not necessarily in this order:

```
10
20
"hello"
true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recurse, selecting only the scalar values:

```
$ cat tmp.json
{
  "a": 10,
  "b": {"d": 20, "e": "hello"},
  "c": {"z": {"f": true}}
}
$ jq 'recurse | scalars' tmp.json
10
20
"hello"
true
```

Comment: `select` here is redundant, since `scalars` already acts as a filter. `recurse|scalars` is sufficient.